# Spyder is not plotting my graph (and stopped running new code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, spyder

It seems as if Spyder (python) is just ignoring my graph. Here is my full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pylab
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import math

metadata = dict() 

with open('practice_data_py18eg(hard).dat', 'r') as data: 
    for lineno,line in enumerate(data):
        if '=' in line:
            parts = line.strip().split('=')
            try:
                metadata[parts[0]]=float(parts[1])
            except TypeError:
                pass
            except ValueError: 
                pass 
        elif '&END' in line: 
            break

data = np.genfromtxt('practice_data_py18eg(hard).dat','float',skip_header=lineno+3)

Intensity = data[:,1]
TwoTheta = data[:,0]

plt.plot(TwoTheta, Intensity, 'x',) 
plt.ylim(1)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
plt.ylabel("log(Intensity)")

peaks, _ = find_peaks(Intensity, height=100)
plt.plot(TwoTheta[peaks], Intensity[peaks],  "ro")

print(peaks)
tp_0 = TwoTheta[peaks[0]]

background = []
for val in TwoTheta: 
    while val<tp_0:
        if (tp_0 - val)>2:
            background.append(val)
print(background)

plt.show()
```

Spyder just returns this:

```
[199 247 400 494 523 634]
```

which is just the indices of my peaks on the graph.

When this started, in the console there was a message saying to untick the 'mute inline plotting' option, which I then did, however nothing has changed.

Also, I just tried to edit my code at the bottom by adding in: 
    print('hello') 
and when I tried to run this, nothing happened.

Help greatly appreciated

Comment: Its just to basic to ask, but as I worked previously in first level support: Have you tried to reboot? Or run the script directly via console?

Comment: There is a setting in Spyder for how to show graphics. Choose inline, if you have switched to something else, to have them show up in the console again.

Comment: yes currently using inline in the preferences (tried also with automatic which didn't work), I have also tried resetting factory settings